Unexpected behavior of Modifier.verticalScroll()?


As you can see in image 1, the Box (highlighted) is not being displayed on screen but if i remove the verticalScroll modifier (form the root composable to ProfileScreen) as in image 2, the box is visible. Why this behaviour and how to fix it?
Putting the content below the box in a column fixes the problem though.(The behavior is same on physical device)

When you use remember scroll state you can't give height in fraction to the views inside of it.
You can use fix height or the default (wrapped content)
If you still want to fraction it somehow then use below code
val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
val screenHeightDp = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp

This will return screen height in dp then you can multiplay it by 0.4 to get the desired height which can be used with remember to set to your AsyncImage, like below
var newHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }

LaunchedEffect(key1 = screenHeightDp) {
    newHeight = (0.4 * screenHeightDp.value).roundToInt().dp
}

Good luck!!!
